# Windows10 VM won't boot after Linux host reinstall

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, virt-manager

There are two SSDs in my setup, one where the OS is installed and another where the qcow2 files for the VMs are stored.

After formating and installing Kubuntu on the first drive and setting everything up again, I cannot boot my old Windows 10 VM that was stored on my second drive.

When starting the VM using virt manager, with the SATA drive that windows 10 is installed on as boot device, only the Shell prompt is shown. I can reinstall Windows if the iso is the boot device and when using an linux iso as live device, I can see that the windows files are still on the drive.

Any ideas how I can boot into the install again?

Comment: Shell prompt, as in the UEFI shell? That would indicate you're trying to boot the VM in UEFI mode. If the Windows 10 system disk is partitioned MBR-style, then it was configured to boot in legacy BIOS mode, not in UEFI mode.

Comment: that was it, thanks. Apparently I saved a completely wrong VM before cleaning up so it was the one with firmware "BIOS" instead of "UEFI x86_64: /usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE_4M.fd"

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible the **Master Boot Record** used for the *Windows 10* installation became over-written or corrupted during your re-installation of your primary OS, Kubuntu?  As such, Windows 10 wouldn't know where to look for it's boot files when it is trying to load.  Have you attempted a Windows 10 OS Recovery with an ISO to repair the **MBR**?  At the command prompt in recovery mode,  try:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /scanos
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```